# How to make news category in typo3 using tx_news

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

Hello I want to create News category in my website. i am using tx_news(News System) Extension for that. but i dont know how to create News Category Please Give me solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create categories in any folder in your page tree, just as most records in TYPO3.

Please consult the manual for further assistense: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/UsersManual/Records/Category/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the version 3.0.0 the sys_category table is used instead of a custom one. This is stated in the changelog, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Misc/Changelog/3-0-0.html

If you are using the old categories, you are able to migrate those.